# I can not seem to reach .resx WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF c# project, and I created two .resx files for changing the language.

[image]

I've set Access Modifier: Public

[image]

Added in .xaml

> xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:Management_Software.Properties"

[image]

When I try to access a string with **{x:Static resx:...}** I see only a .settings file .

Do I have to add the .resx files in App.config,App.xaml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to use resoiurces you have to:
1. Include resource file in xaml like

```
xmlns:resource ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Strings.en_US"
```

2.You can use it with binding like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static resource:Resource1.Greeting}" />
```

if you do these things try to rebuild the project. Xaml cannot figure out that you included new file and generates an error.

In my resource file I have:
Name = Greeting
Value = Sample test

Hope this helps.